# Image tag src-attribute: Session lost with mobile connection

Tags: php, cross-domain, session-cookies

I use an `<img>` tag with an src-attribute pointing to a script that loads the image from a non-public folder. When I test my website with a mobile connection, the scr-attributes path is changed from `src="http://example.com/get_image.php` to `src="http://1.1.1.1/bmi/example.com/get_image.php`, I guess that has something to do with my mobile internet provider. The problem is, the image-providing script cannot identify the session of the incoming request anymore.
On a non-mobile WIFI connection, the src-attribute is not changed, everything works as expected and the session is found.

Comment: This seems really hard to understand. Can you add some detail? What is `http://1.1.1.1.bmi/` in this case, and what does it do to the request? How does the request end up at your script?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp. If you're not giving a full URL in the `src` attribute different browsers try to build the URL differently. If you provide a base tag explicitly, you'll know how relative URLs will be built.

Comment: Like @Pekka웃 has mentioned, more information is needed. If you are using absolute src tags this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, some mobile providers route image requests via their own proxies, to be able to apply more compression (results are usually shitty, but the provider saves a bit of traffic costs.) For this to work, they must be able to manipulate your page on its way to the user’s browser ... so I guess switching to HTTPS might be an easy way to stop them from doing that. (Unless they interfere with that as well ... in that case, they are not a trustworthy provider at all ...)

Comment: Another option would be to pass the session as a GET parameter in the image URL, instead of relying on cookies. (Whether you can live with what that means for the general security of your session, you must decide.)

Comment: I also tried using a base tag with an absolute URL as well as using an absolute URL as src value, but the URL changes in both cases

Comment: @ CBroe: I wouldn't go the $_GET way because the images should stay protected, but I could give the HTTPS proposal a try when nothing else works. However, that already helped, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending my pages with a `Cache-Control: no-transform` header did the trick, at least for my mobile provider. I found the solution after CBroe's hint here: http://stuartroebuck.blogspot.de/2010/08/official-way-to-bypassing-data.html

I am curious how that applies to other mobile companies...